# After redirecting a subdomain to its own new domain name, the old URLs have not been removed from search results

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

I'm using WordPress multisite in subdomain mode.

I created the site `cleonecapital.foracure.org.au`, and later changed the URL of this site to `www.cleonecapital.com`.

In `foracure.org.au`'s .htaccess, I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cleonecapital.foracure.org.au$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cleonecapital.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and I know that `cleonecapital.foracure.org.au` redirects to `www.cleonecapital.com`.

My question is: why does Google still have `cleonecapital.foracure.org.au` in its index?

Just now, I have added the `cleonecapital.foracure.org.au` site to Google Search Console, and I have gone to Google Index > Remove URLs, and submitted the home page URL, and now I see the `cleonecapital.foracure.org.au` site listed as type Site removal.

Is this enough to remove `cleonecapital.foracure.org.au` from the Google search index?

Comment: This often takes months.

Comment: You should not use remove URL option from search console tool, because google might stop crawling that old pages.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing 301 permanent redirects is enough for the subdomain to be removed -- eventually.   However, with just redirects, it may take weeks or even months.  You may also lose many of your SEO rankings because your new domain won't have the same trust metrics as your old domain.

I've never used the site removal feature of Google Search Console, so I can't tell how well it works.   However, I don't think you should be using it in this case.   There is a better tool available.

The Google Search Console change of address tool now supports subdomain moves such as this one.   See: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en   Using this tool should speed the process up significantly and help keep much of your existing SEO value.